# How can I use File Upload to change an image on another Web Form

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I was wondering how to change an image on another page using file upload. I have created an admin panel to be able to change text on other pages and the colours however, I'm struggling on how to do so with an image.

This is through ASP.NET on visual Studio and C#

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: More details ideally needed. Are you storing in database or just on file system or....

Comment: Hi Adam, I'm storing it on the FS. It's a project I'm working on as a "design" that really could be implemented into a full working version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simplified sample code. FileUpload.SaveAs silently overrides existing file.

```
<%--.aspx file --%>
Upload image: <asp:FileUpload ID="fuImage" runat="server" /><br />
Save file as: <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewName" placeholder="/images/myPic.jpg" runat="server" Width="30px"></asp:TextBox><br />
<asp:Button ID="btnRun" runat="server" Text="Save" onClick="btnRun_Click" />

//.aspx.cs file
protected void btnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
fuImage.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~" + txtNewName.Text));
}
```

Comment: WOW! Security hole level 100! At least, put a comment that value from `txtNewName.Text` needs to be sanitized.

Comment: This is _simplified_ sample. In real code you need to check everything you want.

Comment: Simplified sample yeah but it can be improved, Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Store the byte of the image into a property.

```
public byte[] someProperty{get;set;}
HttpPostedFile postedFile = imgFile.PostedFile;
string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);

 if (fileExtension.ToLower() == ".jpg" || fileExtension.ToLower() == ".png")
 {
    Stream stream = postedFile.InputStream;
    BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
    byte[] imgByte = reader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
 }
someProperty = imgByte;
Session["yourImg"] = someProperty;
```

And on the second page where you want to change the `<img>` just get the byte and convert it to string base64.

```
string str = Convert.ToBase64String(Session["yourImg"] as byte[]);
imageID.Src = "data:Image/png;base64," + str;
```

There are many ways in passing value from webform to another webform Session is just one way, but there's a lot, get it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw(v=vs.100).aspx)